# Etimología de la frase popular "Hoy Canta Gardel"

Tags: etimología, chile, cultura-de-masas, argentina

En Chile, es muy frecuente oír el dicho popular "Hoy canta Gardel", aludiendo al singular artista argentino Carlos Gardel. Particularmente se utiliza como forma de mencionar el día de pago o bien cuando se sabe que se recibirá dinero.

Al respecto, surgen diversas hipótesis sobre el origen de esta frase. Una de ellas, refiere el hecho de que cuando cantaba Gardel, éste le entregaba dinero a los más pobres. Otra hipótesis, indica que esta frase surge debido a los altos costos de las entradas a sus conciertos. Otra  hipótesis, hace mención al mercado del Abasto, en donde se encontraban las clases sociales de Buenos Aires, y al oír cantar a Gardel desaparecían las enemistades de clase y todos estaban felices.

He leído varias notas en la web pero carecen de fundamentos sólidos.

Mi pregunta entonces la planteo, no para obtener más hipótesis (pues podría dar para mucho), sino mas bien si alguien conoce acaso antecedentes concretos que fundamenten alguna de éstas u otras hipótesis.

Comment: El origen parece ser inseguro. Me suena más convincente la de que en los días de pago los asalariados se daban el lujo de ir a los bares y poner a Gardel en las máquinas tocadiscos. De paso, en Argentina la frase es totalmente desconocida.

Comment: Como curiosidad, en Argentina la frase "Andá a cantarle a Gardel" significa algo así como "tus problemas no le importan a nadie"

Answer (score 6):

Tu pregunta me dio mucha curiosidad. En Argentina nunca oí esa expresión, con lo cual me parecio mas interensate todavía.
Estuve buscando en internet y yo creo que este [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8dbwCgBw38) da la explicación mas convincente.

En el video el profesor Campusano comenta que es un gran fántico de Gardel y que conoce muchos de sus misterios. Por ende ha leído mucha bibliografía sobre su vida.
Menciona que si bien hay varias etimologías, la más recurrente en los libros se refiere a cuando Gardel no era tan famoso todavía y cantaba en un trio con guitarraba. Cuando él cantaba, la entrada a ver el número era mas costosa, de ahí se dice que cuando cantaba Gardel "había más dinero". Campusano menciona que de ahí se paso a Chile, Cuando canta Gardel hay más dinero, es día de pago.

Muchas veces con frases como la que presentas es prácticamente imposible saber de donde vino, pues no es algo que se pueda identificar en específico de donde salio, dado que es algo que pasa y crece con el tiempo y el uso.

Pero por lo que vi la persona en el video es un consultor en materias lingüísticas y su explicación parece bastante plausible.

Espero te sirva!

Comment: Muchas gracias por la acotación, sin embargo sigue siendo un misterio. Resulta muy curioso para mi saber que en Argentina no conozcan el dicho.

Comment: ¿Podrías resumir la explicación del video? De esa manera la respuesta quedaría autocontenida, lo cual es más apropiado para este sitio

Comment: @leonbloy tienes razón, perdón no me di cuenta!

Answer (score 1):

Domingo 20 de Abril de 2003

Gardel vuelve a cantar

Señor editor:

En la sección cartas de la edición del 6 de abril se presenta una versión errónea sobre el origen de la expresión "hoy canta Gardel" o "cantó Gardel".

La frase en realidad nace en Chile, en tiempo de las discorolas o wurlitzer públicos. Durante las fechas de pago de los trabajadores, que generalmente se realizaba los días viernes, todos íbamos a celebrar a los negocios de la época que tenían discorolas, donde seleccionábamos los discos que nos gustaban. Y entre esos, por supuesto, estaban los del gran Carlitos Gardel.

Esa es la única verdad.

Ricardo Barraza V.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Spanish.SE! ¿Es esto una copia de algo publicado en otra web? Si es así, por favor indica la fuente.

Comment: Suena muy razonable, sin embargo son muchas las explicaciones por lo cual es necesario tener referencias mas específicas.

Answer (score 1):

Creo tiene relación con que en general los artistas en Chile han sufrido por la informalidad de los trabajos...De ahí otro proverbio que dice que Artista Pagado, Canta Afinado, muchos artistas solicitaban sus remuneraciones previo a la presentación y tiene relación con incumplimientos de pago...

Comment: Bienvenido a spanish.stackexchange.com Quizá sería buena idea que revisases las secciones de [Tour] y [Help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Date cuenta de que la pregunta especifica que no desea más hipótesis, sino fundamento para alguna de ellas (la que sea). Tu respuesta mejoraría mucho si pudieses añadir alguna referencia para respladar tus afirmaciones.

Answer (score 1):

Yo sabía que en una fecha determinada vino Gardel a Chile...y la fecha coincidió con el pago de los trabajadores. ...y de ahí quedó la frase famosa sólo en Chile "Hoy canta Gardel "

Answer (score 0):

Carlos Gardel solía hacer presentaciones musicales para los vecinos  del Barrio La Boca, y no sólo cantaba sino que también regalaba dinero a los más desposeídos.
Estos encuentros se avisaban de boca en boca, utilizando el conocido término :
" ¡ Mañana canta Gardel !, advirtiendo a  los necesitados, que si asistían podrían
recibir un "billetito".